# Mass MP3 File Stretcher?

Tags: audio, audio-editing

Say for example I have hundreds of .mp3 files that I want to stretch the audio 2x in every single file, but don't want to do it individually. What software would let me do this?

Comment: some additional information like "on which OS should/must it run?", "which budget do you have?", "is F(L)OSS required?" would be good...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this in Audacity following the guide [*How To Quickly Edit Multiple Files in Audacity*](https://www.howtogeek.com/57571/how-to-quickly-edit-multiple-files-in-audacity/).

You can chain effects to be applied to multiple files. The effect you are probably looking for is ChangeSpeed. You can then select multiple files and you're good to go.

[Link to Audacity if you don't have it yet](http://www.audacityteam.org/download/).